# Are all badges "especially helpful"?

Tags: discussion, badges, zero-score-badges

Recently I made a feature request for a new badge to be given to people whose bounty get wasted because no answer was given to that question.

Suffice it to say (for whatever reason) the request was not well received and was susequently deleted by me. One of the user pointed out this:

> Besides gaining reputation with your questions and answers, **you receive badges for being especially helpful**. Badges appear on your profile page, flair, and your posts. (emphasis added as this was how it was presented to me)

And the person asked me how the suggested batch was helpful. Are all badges helpful? I don't understand how the following badges are helpful:

1. Tumbleweed badge
2. Tenacious
3. Unsung hero
4. Precognitive
5. Peer Pressure

Comment: Badges are achievements. Also many of them are for good behaviour like deleting bad posts (Peer Pressure)

Answer (score 8):

Tumbleweed isn't really a "normal" badge, it's more of a "consolation prize." "Sorry you didn't get an answer or any responses; here, have a shiny badge."

Tenacious and Unsung Hero are for encouraging users to **post useful answers, even if they don't get upvotes.** This might be for a number of reasons, for example, a low-traffic tag.

How does Precognitive *not* encourage helpful behavior? It's awarded to users who help out a site in is earliest stages, **at the very time when it needs the most help.**

Peer Pressure absolutely encourages positive behavior. Deleting low quality content **increases the overall quality of posts on the site.**

Comment: Note that some truly negative badges were removed, as far as I remember correctly.

Comment: I think Peer Pressure was listed because it's somewhat of a mark of shame.  The name does not help, especially in cultures where yielding to peer pressure is considered weakness.

Comment: I 100% believe that the Peer Pressure badge is a "mark of shame" -- https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371830/352329